# Multiple iterations of columns to analyse correlation

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, iteration, correlation

I have many columns with many substrings values, I need to know the count of possible combinations with the intention to find correlations between them. However, they are many different columns (approx 20) and I need all kind of combinations (2 of them, 3 of them, 4 of them etc.)

I have this code that works fine, but it only gives me the possible combinations of all columns and I would need to recreate the code for every possible combination.

```
from collections import Counter
import pandas as pd
# Define your fields as lists of strings
d = {'field1' : ["apple", "banana", "orange", "apple", "pear"],
'field2' : ["banana", "pear", "orange", "pear", "apple"],
'field3' : ["orange", "banana", "apple", "pear", "pear"],
'field4' : ["orange", "apple", "banana", "pear", "pear"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
# Combine the fields into a list of tuples, where each tuple contains the values
# for each field at a particular position
all_fields = zip(df['field1'], df['field2'], df['field3'], df['field4'])

# Count the frequency of each unique combination of values across all fields
comb_counts = Counter(all_fields)

# Print out the counts for each combination
for comb, count in comb_counts.items():
    print(comb, count)
```

The output is

```
('apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'orange') 1
('banana', 'pear', 'banana', 'apple') 1
('orange', 'orange', 'apple', 'banana') 1
('apple', 'pear', 'pear', 'pear') 1
('pear', 'apple', 'pear', 'pear') 1
('apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'orange') 1
('banana', 'pear', 'banana', 'apple') 1
('orange', 'orange', 'apple', 'banana') 1
('apple', 'pear', 'pear', 'pear') 1
('pear', 'apple', 'pear', 'pear') 1
```

This will only output combination where all 4 columns are, or I can manually add only 3, or 2 of those columns.

I need an output that has all possible combinations already appended and with a count of them.

for example, if I only use the last 2 columns, appended with the first 3.

```
('orange', 'orange') 1
('banana', 'apple') 1
('apple', 'banana') 1
('pear', 'pear') 2
('apple', 'banana', 'orange') 1
('banana', 'pear', 'banana') 1
('orange', 'orange', 'apple') 1
('apple', 'pear', 'pear') 1
('pear', 'apple', 'pear') 1
```

The code should output all possible field combinations as a data frame (one column with combinations, another with which fields were combined, and one with count of occurrences), in this version is just printed, an example is below.

| combination | count | fields |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ('orange', 'orange') | 1 | field3, field4 |
| ('banana', 'apple') | 1 | field3, field4 |
| ('apple', 'banana') | 1 | field3, field4 |
| ('pear', 'pear') | 2 | field3, field4 |
| ('apple', 'banana', 'orange') | 1 | field1, field2, field3 |
| ('banana', 'pear', 'banana') | 1 | field1, field2, field3 |
| ('orange', 'orange', 'apple') | 1 | field1, field2, field3 |
| ('apple', 'pear', 'pear') | 1 | field1, field2, field3 |
| ('pear', 'apple', 'pear') | 1 | field1, field2, field3 |

My goal is to find hidden correlations between fields.
Thank you for the help.